# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: error-handling, access-denied

I have been running the below script for a few months now, but as of today, when i went to run it again i got the following error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden: Access is denied.
```

I tried adding in a delay using sleep, but that did not seem to work. It appears the denial is coming from Finviz.com, which is where i run a specified screen and scrape tickers. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the sudden denial?

```
from datetime import datetime
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from time import sleep


#used for removing parts of the url collection if an error occurs
print('Running Screen...')
collection  = ['ar=180','r=21&ar=180','r=41&ar=180','r=61&ar=180','r=81&ar=180','r=101&ar=180','r=121&ar=180','r=141&ar=180','r=161&ar=180','r=181&ar=180','r=201&ar=180','r=221&ar=180','r=241&ar=180']
for url in collection: #scrape multiple pages
        my_url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=141&f=cap_smallover,fa_eps5years_pos,fa_grossmargin_o10,fa_netmargin_pos,fa_opermargin_pos,fa_sales5years_o5,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o1000,ta_beta_o0.5&ft=2&' + str(url)
        sleep(15)
        uClient = ur(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #find ticker
        stock_tickers = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"screener-link-primary"})
        for tickers in stock_tickers: #find all of the tickers
                ticker = tickers.text
                collection  = [ticker]
                for url in collection: #scrape multiple pages
                        #balance sheet data
                        my_url1 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/balance-sheet?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                            'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url1, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                        #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_balancesheet = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_balancesheet = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.set_index(0) 
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_balancesheet.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_balancesheet.columns)[1::]
                        #income statement data
                        my_url2 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/financials?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                                'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url2, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                            #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_incomestatement = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_incomestatement = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.set_index(0)
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_incomestatement.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_incomestatement.columns)[1::]
                        # cash flow data
                        my_url3 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/cash-flow?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                                'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url3, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                            #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_cashflow = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_cashflow = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.set_index(0)
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_cashflow.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_cashflow.columns)[1::]
                        writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Financial statements/"+ ticker + '.xlsx')
                        df_incomestatement.to_excel(writer,'Income Statement')
                        df_balancesheet.to_excel(writer,'Balance Sheet')
                        df_cashflow.to_excel(writer,'Statement of Cash Flows')
                        writer.save()
                        print('Collecting data for ' + ticker + '...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, fixed it, just didn't send the user agent header